# Clojure Editor written in Clojure

Tags: emacs, clojure, editor, slime, swank

Note: I'm not looking for LightTable. I really am looking for a Clojure Editor *implemented* in Clojure.

Recently, I've been studying slime/swank/elisp. Although it's an amazing system, I actually don't understand (beside reasons of historical artifacts) why I should:

(*) write parts of my code in Clojure, and yet code up editor plugins in elisp

It seems like besides the fact that emacs/swank/elisp already exists, there is no reason to prefer elisp over clojure.

Thus, my question: are there any usable projects to implement a clojure editor/ide in clojure? It's okay if it's less developed than emacs/slime/swank -- I don't mind writing more clojure code.

Thanks!

Comment: One can typically achieve *amazing* customizations with very litte amounts of elisp. In addition by being part of a bigger community you can take advantage of already existing solutions for almost every issue that may arise.

Comment: is LightTable not going to be written in Clojure ? I thought that was the point

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Clooj](https://github.com/arthuredelstein/clooj) is implemented in Clojure and people seem to like it. I don't believe it has any extension mechanisms yet though, but when it does, I'm sure they'll be written in Clojure.

Comment: This looks more scriptable than both enclojure & counterclockwise.

Answer (score 2):

LightTable was just open sourced https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable

Answer (score 1):

There are a few newer editors written in Clojure (or ClojureScript)

- https://github.com/bodil/catnip
- https://github.com/hraberg/deuce (Emacs under Clojure)
- https://github.com/oakes/Nightcode

Answer (score 0):

Nightcode is excellent, written in Clojure and actively developed,
see https://github.com/oakes/Nightcode

Comment: Please elaborate: What about plugins?